# How can i save all output to the screen while still displaying it?

Tags: c, shell

I am currently writing a custom shell for a CS course.

It is a basic shell that reads in user input, and checks for shell functions, and then forks itself and passes the commands that were parsed to execvp().

I need to save the output from the screen into a text file while the shell is currently being run. I looked into freopen but that cut off all printing to the screen.

Can anyone give me a hint in which direction to look to perform this functionality?

Comment: Look at [ttyrec](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en) , [ttygif](https://github.com/icholy/ttygif), [termrec](http://angband.pl/termrec.html).

Comment: BTW, this is something that POSIX-standard shells *don't do* -- they leave file descriptors alone unless explicitly told to redirect it somewhere else, hence the utility of tools such as `tee`.

Comment: ...moreover, it's a thing that's not done for very good reason: If you redirect stderr and stdout together, you're discarding information that the program generated in terms of which content goes into which bucket. If you redirect them separately, even if you recombine them later, then it's impossible to guarantee that the recombined order matches the original order.

Comment: ...`script`, `termrec`, the recording operations of `tmux` and `screen`, etc. work around this by providing their own TTY, but that's a very invasive operation, something it's not a good idea (and not at all traditional) for a shell to perform.

Comment: Could be an XY problem. What do you want to achieve with recording the output?

Comment: I need to be able to save a record of the shell running. Normally i would just write to each file descriptor separate but I want to capture the output from the execvp calls. So when i call "ls" it should print to the screen and be stored in a file.

Comment: You probably have the `script` command installed already. If you don't need to record any timing information, that's the simplest recorder to use.

Comment: I looked into script, but it also reads in stderr. stderr is being used to print statements we dont want read in by this functionality. Thats why i have been trying to read only from stdout

Comment: If you only want to redirect stdout, and don't need to preserve ordering information (you **can't** record only stdout and not stderr without discarding that, except via invasive methods such as sysdig/strace/truss/etc) that's what `tee` is for.

Comment: ...again, though: **Normal POSIX-compliant shells don't do this**, because it has bad side effects: If you have a line written to stdout, and a line following it written to stderr, and another line to stdout, and you need to know exactly which stdout line the stderr line is next to, what you're trying to accomplish will necessarily throw away that information, because a well-defined ordering only exists at all between writes to the same file descriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something which will read from standard input and write same thing into both standard output as well standard error, that way you can print one, while save other in file.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1000

int main ()
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t read_size;

    while ((read_size = read (STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        if (write (STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, read_size) <= 0 ||
            write (STDERR_FILENO, buffer, read_size) <= 0)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If program is called `dupl` then you can do something like this

`ls | ./dupl 2> file`

This will display and as well save standard output of `ls` into `file`

Comment: I don't gather that the OP wants to discard the original contents of stderr. Also, if this is what they want to do, why couldn't they just use `tee`?

Comment: He can still save stderr. I didn't know about `tee`.

Comment: Hmm. You're right -- I didn't think things through well enough, but original stderr will go straight to the console rather than going through the pipeline. So -- not wrong, just needless (in the light of having a POSIX-specified equivalent standard).